# Should I use a switch statement to associate CSS IDs with JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function getVariableFromID(ID) {
    switch (ID) {
    case "GTA1":
        return GTA1;
    case "GTA2":
        return GTA2;
    case "GTA3":
        return GTA3;
            ...
    case "GTJ0":
        return GTJ0;
    }
}
```

So I have a switch statement in my code that takes the #id of a DIV tag using .attr and associates it with a javascript variable. Each numeric code represents one square on a chessboard-like grid. There are 100 squares. Is there an easier or more compact method for performing a calculation like this, or is this the simplest way?

Comment: in this code,  getVariableFromID(x) == eval(x), expect eval works for all keys without custom coding.

Comment: I've heard that eval() is bad practice though. And I only have a specific set of variables that I need to evaluate. But you are right, that would simplify the code somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *array* instead of 100 *variable* and hundred conditions in switch. Array could be array of *strings/numbers or objects*. Declare array with number of elements you want and get the number from `ID` to use as `index` of array.

```
arrGTA = ["somevalue1", "somevalue2"]; //Could be array of strings/numbers or objects.
function getVariableFromID(ID) {
    idx = parseInt(ID.replace("GTA", ""));
    return arrGTA[idx-1];
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try this out. I already added the objects to an array to check for tile.selected==true as part of the game piece moving code, so this just might be a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I accept what Adil said you can directly return ID

```
function getVariableFromID(ID) {
        return ID;
}
```

Comment: He is not returning the string i.e id but variable.